# Where to edit the responsive html codes for the main page for my website

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, jhtml

I own a website called http://elitemaths.com.au/. Currently, the main page modules seem to be working fine on a desktop browser with "maths is hard..." div as well as the "Fulfill your...". I have attached a screenshot of this.[image].

However, when I load the same page on my iphone 6, these divs are not working properly. The following is what I see on my phone. [image].

Being fairly new to Joomla and html, I have no idea where would I go and try to sort this. I have had a look at the template.css file in the 
 "/public_html/templates/elitemaths/local/css/themes/elitemaths" directory but cannot find where this module sits.

Could anyone suggest which file to work on to fix this issue? And could anyone suggest a possible fix if possible?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those divs have the classes **h2 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm**

The following code hides those divs.

```
Line: 6685
.visible-xs, .visible-sm, .visible-md, .visible-lg {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The reason that they are visible in large screens is this code:

```
Line: 6795
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.visible-lg {
display: block !important;
}.....
```

you can find both codes in:
**http://elitemaths.com.au/templates/elitemaths/local/css/themes/elitemaths/bootstrap.css**

You can remove the class **visible-lg** from the first code or even better edit the second.

Comment: Thank you guys. That actually fixed the issue with the first bit of the text with the "Maths is Hard. ....". Wow!

Comment: Do you reckon you can give me tips on how to fix the second text with "Fulfill your potential ..."? Many thanks

Comment: Check the file http://elitemaths.com.au/templates/elitemaths/local/css/themes/elitemaths/template.css for @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.tp-intro {
 padding:60px 0;
}
.tp-intro-feature {
 padding:60px 0;
 text-align:center;
 background:#fff;
}
the block is there but the background and padding changes.
the class you are after is tp-intro-feature

I suggest you install Firefug Addon for Firefox or use any of the other browsers inspect tools it will help you a lot.

Comment: I am definitely going to try this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Don't really know for your template but it can be the good file. It is generally a huge file :)  It is *protostar/css/template.css* for the *protostar* template shipped with Joomla.
Once found, you should search the string *@media*. These are called Media Queries. They are used to define new style rules for different media types. You can type something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) :{
    p {
        background-color: red; } }
```

In that case, paragraphs will have a red background-color when seen from a device which is a *screen* whose max resolution is 640px.
The word *screen* is important. It is the media type. Because you can specify things like *print* for printers !
This is the very basic principle.